# How to find the length of an array by filtering by a parameter value in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was building a chat server, where i need to get the number of messages that is not marked as
seen . below is my schema

```
const ChatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    chatId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    messages: [
        {
            message: { type: String, required: true },
            sendBy: { type: String, required: true },
            sendTo: { type: String, required: true },
            seen: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            date: { type: Date, default: Date.now()}
        },
    ],

})
```

I have tried the following code but it always returns 1

```
const unSeenCount=await Chat.find({ chatId: chatId }, 
            { messages : { $elemMatch : { seen : false } } })
        
        console.log(`unseen count is ${unSeenCount.length}`);
```

Comment: Got a solution for the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/73105055/16312505

Answer (score 0):

The first object in the mongoose query is the filter which is what you were using in the second object. You can also use `count` to get the count returned by the filter query.

Try this:

```js
const unSeenCount = await Chat.count({
    messages: {
        $elemMatch: {
            seen: false
        }
    }
})

console.log(`unseen count is ${unSeenCount}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the countDocuments Method

```
const unSeenCount=await Chat.countDocuments({{ chatId: chatId }, 
        { messages : { $elemMatch : { seen : false } } }})
    
    console.log(`unseen count is ${unSeenCount}`);
```

Comment: it also return 1 always. it actually counts the the number of documents with query                { chatId: chatId }   not further