# How to find the length of an array by filtering by a parameter value in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was building a chat server, where I need to get the number of messages that are marked as `seen: false`.

below is my schema,

```
const ChatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    chatId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    messages: [
        {
            message: { type: String, required: true },
            sendBy: { type: String, required: true },
            sendTo: { type: String, required: true },
            seen: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            date: { type: Date, default: Date.now()}
        },
    ],

})
```

I have tried the following code but it always returns 1

```
const unSeenCount=await Chat.find({ chatId: chatId }, 
            { messages : { $elemMatch : { seen : false } } })
        
        console.log(`unseen count is ${unSeenCount.length}`);
```

I think it only gets the documents with the
query  `{ chatId: chatId }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to calculate from projection,

- use `findOne` method because you want one chat's messages count
- check just `chatId` condition in the query
- add projection

  - `$filter` to iterate loop of `seen` array from messages and check is any false
  - `$size` to count to total elements in above-filtered array
- add `lean()` at the end, and it will return javascript object instead of mongoose document

```
const unSeenCount = await Chat.findOne(
  { chatId: chatId },
  {
    count: {
      $size: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$messages.seen",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this", false] }
        }
      }
    },
    // add more fields if you need them in the result.
  }
).lean();  

console.log(`unseen count is ${unSeenCount.count}`);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H-EIU2PtlUZ)

Comment: this works!! thanks. but i dont know why unSeenCount.count returns undefined, but now i can print unSeenCount which has data

Comment: *i can print unSeenCount which has data* => which data? are you not getting count property in `unSeenCount`?

Comment: console.log(unSeenCount);                                
console.log(unSeenCount.count);                                                                              {
  _id: new ObjectId("62de3baf7df7e4e991975b25"),
  count: 14,
  messages: []
}
undefined

Comment: its there. but couldn't print

Comment: try `lean()` after `findOne(...).lean()` method.

Answer (score 0):

try using **filter** instead of **find**:

```
const unSeenCount=await Chat.filter({ chatId: chatId }, 
        { messages : { $elemMatch : { seen : false } } })
    
    console.log(`unseen count is ${unSeenCount.length}`);
```

Comment: there is no `filter` method in mongoose npm, you have suggested a Javascript function, this will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$elemMatch`, it will return you all documents that satisfy that criteria. Therefore if document has an array that satisfy that criteria, the whole document will be returned. The MongoDB will not "count" how much appereances are there in an array.
Your query will return you either 0 or 1, depends if there is at least one message with `seen : false` in an array or not.

You can use `unwind` operation: [MongoDB: Count of matching array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648169/mongodb-count-of-matching-array-elements) . It will allow you to work with objects inside array in same way as with documents. It is not very efficient though, so if you have a lot of messages and you do this operation often, it can consume a lot of MongoDB resources. So if you need to do this (or similar operations) with messages frequently, it is better to create separate collection for messages.

Comment: could you give an example schema for chat collection storing messages(Like you mentioned), and can be accessed with a chat id. thank you

Comment: @muhammedjasir - well you will have to create chats (ChatSchema would contain chatId and the two people messaging between each other) and the MessageSchema will contain chatId (reference to existing chat document), message, seen and date.

In theory you dont need even chatId, you just have messages between two people and you know them by filtering by sendBy and sendTo

Comment: I was actually trying to build like you said. but i couldnt find a way to model like the same with mongo db. thats why i did it like how now it is. And even now i dont understand how to model like list of message objects has a parent property chatId as a collection

Comment: @muhammedjasir - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008555/creating-a-foreign-key-relationship-in-mongoose